When will the Apollo flags disintegrate?
The flags from Apollo 12, 16, and 17 are confirmed to be intact by the LRO (Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter). However, radiation and extreme temperature are slowly disintegrating the flags. So, approximately, when will the Apollo flags disintegrate?
For this purpose, disintegrate means that a significant part of the flag is no longer attached to the main flag and the flag pole.

Related question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41168/did-us-flags-on-the-moon-turn-white

I wonder: Who cares? Isn't it a remainder of imperialism, like "We were first to put our flag there, so it (the moon) is ours"?

@U.Windl according to the Outer Space Treaty (US signed it in 1967) no one owns the moon.

@Starship That's why I said "like"...

The Apollo 11 flag (from the iconic photo) has probably already disintegrated

The (Apollo 11’s) flag is probably gone. Buzz Aldrin saw it knocked over by the rocket blast as he and Neil Armstrong left the moon 39 summers ago. Lying there in the lunar dust, unprotected from the sun’s harsh ultraviolet rays, the flag’s red and blue would have bleached white in no time. Over the years, the nylon would have turned brittle and disintegrated. … Dennis Lacarrubba, whose New Jersey-based company, Annin, made the flag and sold it to NASA for $5.50 in 1969, considers what might happen to an ordinary nylon flag left outside for 39 years on Earth, let alone on the moon. He thinks for a few seconds. “I can’t believe there would be anything left,” he concludes. “I gotta be honest with you. It’s gonna be ashes.”

The remaining Apollo landing flags are still upright and flying, as confirmed by the shadows they cast on the lunar surface (Lunar Reconnaissance mission photos)

And that's the flag itself, not the pole

What is really being seen in these five images is the flag shadow itself and not the flag pole shadow.  The flag pole is only about 7/8ths of an inch in diameter. LRO cameras can at best see down to 0.45 meters (1.5 feet) which is the equivalent to one pixel width in the images and .55 meters (1.8 feet) which is equivalent to one pixel of height.  This resolution is just good enough to see the drooped flag shadow (estimated to be from 6 inches to 1.5 feet).  Even if the drooped flag is narrower than the .45 meter resolution, since one pixel of the camera’s optics is an average over an entire area of coverage, the flag’s shadow can substantially dim a large fraction of this area and, on average, reduce the pixel illumination even though it cannot blacken it completely.

How long can they last? It's hard to say. Before the LRO mission, the theory was they were long gone. These were not any sort of heavy-duty material like the rest of the lunar mission equipment. They were standard nylon flags. It's likely they're not in good shape. The temperature swings and UV radiation have likely taken their toll. It could be they would fall apart if you merely touched them. We just can't recreate the lunar environment here on Earth to know for sure.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
